# Would rubber carriage wheels significantly improve the efficiency of horse-drawn carriage travel?

Tags: alternate-history, engineering, transportation

So, suppose a medieval society knows how to create vulcanized rubber. (As long as they have rubber sap, sulphur, and the recipe, it shouldn't be outside of their capabilities. The process is super simple, and Charles Goodyear stumbled onto the process by accident.)

It just occurred to me that these people would probably use rubber tires for horse-carts rather than the iron tires used in the real world.

Would these rubber tires make horse carts better able to traverse rough terrain, and thus increase the effectiveness of horse cart travel?

Note: just because they have rubber tires doesn’t necessarily mean they have pneumatic tires. Rubber tires could, in this context, mean a solid rubber tire. For the context of this discussion, I would like an answer regarding both possibilities. That is, I am interested in knowing whether pneumatic rubber tires or solid rubber tires would significantly improve performance on a dirt road.

Comment: The roads are mostly dirt and mud, with the occasional concrete or cobblestone road.

Comment: My next door neighbour is the man to ask, breeds ponies for carriage racing and other. He's asleep at present. I notice though that his training-carriages have pneumatic tyres, but that may just be better on the roads - so not an answer.

Comment: Do you mean vulcanized?

Comment: Rubber can be galvanised, but it isn't what Goodyear was doing!

Comment: Whoops. I have replaced "galvanized" with "vulcanized". I could have sworn I had that right the first time.

Comment: Tyre surface (rubber vs iron) is 90% comfort for the passengers, and 10% comfort for the axles. Now have your guy invent *sprung suspension*, and even with iron tyres the carriages and wagons will be much, much more terrain-adaptable. And will draw a bit easier too, as rolling resistance is linearly coupled with *unsprung* mass, and only very indirectly to total vehicle mass. P.s. Leather tyres were a thing since Roman era, for luxury transport. Cost and durability favored iron running surface though.

Comment: Rubber tires aren't more efficient, they make the carriage more *durable and bearable*.  Everything (except perhaps the rubber itself) will last longer, most especially the driver and passengers.  Riding in a hard-wheeled carriage on a rough road is a battering trial of endurance, even with leaf-springs.

Comment: When I was a kid in 1950s London, we had coal delivered by a guy with a horse and cart, and also we were often passed by travelling scrap collectors likewise. In each case the carts had rubber tyred wheels just like the ones on motor trucks. The front pair pivoted. We use the spelling 'tyre' in the UK.

Comment: Just to point out, the question has a _False Premise_.  The OP seems to think that soft suspension is _more_ efficient than hard. That is false. Soft suspension wastes energy by deforming the suspension elements (springs, tyres), and much of that energy is lost as frictional heating. It's more _comfortable_, which is maybe what he means.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Wooden Leaf Suspension Made Flexible Carriage Wheels Obsolete

The Ancient Egyptians beat modern man to the idea of flexible wheel materials... by a LOT. From around 3500-2000 years ago, wheels were normally made from flexible wood or wicker to conform to the ground and absorb the shock of rough terrain... basically acting very much like the rubber wheels on a modern wheel.

Around 1000BCE, you start to see the first iron-tire wheels.  They reduced drag and were more durable making them useful in certain contexts like chariot racing on a properly prepared field or for transporting heavy loads, over short distances, but they lacked any shock protection; so, they were not popular in any general since.

However, some time between about 500BCE and 55BCE, the British Celts invented the first true suspension system.  This suspension system was very similar to a modern leaf suspension system used by many trucks, just made out of wood instead of spring steel.

When the Romans adopted this suspension system and paired it with hot shrunk iron tires, this combination spread very quickly throughout Europe and became the standard for wagon construction up until the invention  of the automobile.

The reason automobiles went back to the flexible tire design was because a car has to produce its own propulsion.  This means it needs friction with the ground in order to move at all.  However, carriage wheels only need to be pulled so reducing friction with smooth hardwood or metal tired wheels improves their performance over flexible materials.  So if you were to introduce rubber to a wheel-wright any time between about 55BCE and the late 1800s, they would intrinsically understand that it is a bad material to make wagon tires out of.

The only performance advantage of rubber tires over steel for a carriage has more to do with the road than the carriage.  Modern roads are paved with concreate or asphalt.  Softer tires are easier on a hard road; so, if your medieval community also has significant networks of paved roads, a local lord may require that you use wood or rubber wheels so he does not have to repave so often.

Comment: I wonder if "Mini" style solid rubber shocks would work here as a suspension system

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Probably not as well... leaf and spring suspension systems are very durable compared to your car's tires.  Replacing them with heavy duty balloons would probably cause them to fail much more often.

Comment: Minis didn't use baloons. They used literal 'blocks' of solid rubber as shock absorbers cause it was cheaper.

Comment: Steel and wood are actually much more elastic and compressible than vulcanized latex, and their greater strengths makes them better for taking a heavy load and repeated deformations. Vulcanized rubber balls compress because they are full of air. In it's solid relaxed form, it's like trying to compress water, you can displace it, but not compress it.  This means you can't put it in a fully contained system, which could cause alignment issues.  Also, once it reaches about 70% compression deformation, it fails https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCsIN9OrEw0

Answer (score 22):

The process is vulcanized, not galvanized.  (That's coating metal with another metal to reduce corrosion, e.g. zinc-coated steel.)  But in general rubber tires would be a bit less efficient, due to sidewall flex. That's why railroads have steel wheels running on steel rails.

On the other hand, rubber tires would be more comfortable, and quieter.  Solid rubber tires were used from at least the mid-1800s.  The pneumatic tire was invented in 1845, but didn't catch on: https://www.wired.com/2007/12/dayintech-1210/

If you're interested, you can buy both solid and pneumatic tires for your horse-drawn carriage, so you could easily do some testing.

Comment: I mean, smooth hard on smooth hard is optimal, but when you don't have a choice about the road surface it helps if the wheel can deform to match contours in the road surface so that the road feels flatter than it really is when pulling. Otherwise you might literally have to pull the wooden wheel up a rock on the road.

Comment: @DKNguyen " Otherwise you might literally have to pull the wooden wheel up a rock on the road." this is what a ([well-tuned](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda2.html)) suspension is meant to achieve, springs deforming just enough to absorb-release the energy of wheel going up the rock rather than the entire carriage going up the rock.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Remember that pulling an (ideal) wheel up a rock is conservative: the energy you put in to go up is returned going down.  There are a number of reasons to have soft rubber tires for dirt roads (better traction, more weight-bearing area, &c), but efficiency isn't one of them.

Comment: @PcMan: Sorry, but that is incorrect.  Maybe the wheel freefalls down for a rather small obstruction when you're travelling at high speeds.  Not for dirt road sized obstructions at horse-drawn carriage speeds.  Shock absorbers are for the purpose of improving ride comfort - and handling, reducing vibration, &c.  Nor do non-pneumatic tires reduce friction: try it.  Or try pulling a cart with tires at different pressures: the higher the pressure, the easier it rolls.

Comment: @PcMan the truth is somewhere in the middle. Because it's rare that the wheel free falls afterwards, part of the energy is returned in the direction of movement (unlike for a stepping mechanism)

Comment: @PcMan can you put a dimension for that "normal carriage wheel size"? You may have a point there, I'll need to do some maths to verify something going against my intuition.

Comment: @PcMan "Carriage not wagon" Noted now. Was thinking more of something like [this](https://fastly.4sqi.net/img/general/width960/15456013_wSp3gVaMFKcIaXopUPMAua1gOQCol-kAC-VCdJJCxGQ.jpg). "24 inch wheels. Hits 1cm obstacle...it only hits the ground 33.75 cm further along the road" Does it mean riding a carriage over cobblestone is more akin to flying than rolling? Typical cobblestone sizes are [5-9" x 4-6"](https://www.piecesofhistory.net/pages/faqs.html). Worst case, the wheel travels half a cobblestone until hits its peak (12-15cm) and then flies for 30cm. Doesn't feel quite right.

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi: For a rough practical comparison, ride a mountain bike on various dirt surfaces.  On level ground, of course, so as to approximate the speed of a horse-drawn vehicle.  Which would be the horse(s) walking or trotting: canter or gallop aren't sustainable for long distances.

Comment: @PcMan: Re "A carriage at speed over cobblestones...", driving a carriage (or riding a horse) at speed is something you don't do very often,  Horses aren't like motor vehicles: they can't go at high speeds for very long - a mile or two at a gallop, maybe as much as 5 miles at a canter.  Running a horse over cobblestones is also a good way to cause hoof problems, pulled tendons, or even break a leg.

Comment: @PcMan: Because you wrote "a carriage at speed".  Granted it's imprecise and subjective, but I consider a trot to be a fairly slow gait, not "at speed".

Comment: forget it. I'm not headbutting with someone unwilling to use facts rather than preconceived opinions. Withdrawing from this discussion.

Answer (score 20):

No, I don't think that rubber tires (pneumatic or not) increases efficiency high enough to produce a "revolution in horse powered carting".

Using rubber tires on carriages has some value on efficiency, but is the value is limited to distributing the weight of the carriage on a larger surface on *soft soils* - thus preventing the sinking of the carriage. On paved roads, the use of rubber has to do mostly with the comfort of the ride - less high frequency vibrations and noise.

The most efficiency gains for a carriage comes from:

- using larger wheels - less prone to follow the small irregularities of the road - important at low speed, where the inertia in the "forward" direction is low. Also important, for larger wheels, the momentum of the friction between the wheel hub and the axle (at the bearing level) is smaller when compared with the momentum of the (external) traction force. Speaking of axle/hub - larger wheels means less revolutions, less revolutions means less energy transformed into heat in the wheel bearing.
- spring suspension - counts mainly in high speed situation - a *sudden/momentary* "climb" over a rock means displacing only the weight of the wheel and deforming the spring rather than a moving the weight entire carriage over the rock (the more efficiency is to be gained by the closer to the ideal [critical damping](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda2.html) of the suspension). High speed also puts a pressure on the size of the wheel, larger wheels are less maneuverable, so there's a need of some other solution to compensate.

The things started to change with the increased popularity of the car and trucks, where:

1. the surface of the tire is used to transmit the traction on the ground
2. higher speeds and vehicle control make skidding a problem that didn't exist on... vehicles with external propulsion
3. the weight of the "carriage" itself is quite high so that the pressure on the road is a contributing factor to the cost of road maintenance (experimentally determined as [going with the 4th power of the weight/axle](https://www.insidescience.org/news/how-much-damage-do-heavy-trucks-do-our-road) in the 1950s). When rolling space is not an issue, one can dispense oneself of the tires in the [favor of larger steel wheels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xU_fshxE3Gk).

Comment: A reasonably fat tyre (e.g. mountain bike ratherdeforms than road bike) provides a decent bit of effective suspension for climbing over rocks.  Assuming everything is rigid except the tyre, the effective height of a rock or step is reduced by the amount the tyre compresses as it rolls over.

Comment: I reckon the biggest win for mountain biking case comes on the line of control rather than the effort saved.

Comment: I suppose that if rubber tires were less efficient while providing more comfort, they would readily become a status symbol for the wealthy.

Comment: @Chris H: But compare the effort needed to propel a mountain bike on a smooth road, compared to a road bike with skinny, high-pressure tires.  The problem is that the skinny tires either sink in on soft dirt, or get a lot of side force on rocks.

Comment: Pneumatic tyres did increase the efficiency of bicycle wheels on paved roads, and led to "safety" bicycles being faster than the older "ordinary" (penny-farthing). While a large rubber tyred wheel would have an even lower rolling resistance, the smaller wheel has an aerodynamic advantage. (There are other factors involved too, like the change from direct drive to geared chain drive.)

Comment: @jamesqf I do, quite often, but I don't think there are any smooth roads to worry about in this case, and on slightly rough gravel of dried dirt I can do very similar speeds on my tourer and my MTB (I've tested)

Comment: @Chris H: But I would expect that's because your touring tires are sinking in to the dirt/gravel, thus creating more friction.  At least that's my own experience.  Or compare an ordinary mountain bike with one of the newer really fat tired ones on soft sand or snow.  It's about the increased weight-bearing area (contact patch), not what the tire's made of.

Comment: @jamesqf my touring tyres are fairly wide (35mm) slicks, run pretty hard, and I don't sink into the dried dirt. The gravel I also ran this test on is very coarse, like 50mm pieces, so comparable to the width of my mtb tyres, and loose. After rain the mtb wins by a lot

Comment: "...things started to change with the increased popularity of the car and trucks, where ... the surface of the tire is used to transmit the traction on the ground" <- this is the real winning point here.  Bikes and automobiles need the traction of the rubber wheel, but for a horse drawn carriage, the traction comes from the horse.  So, the wheels themselves perform better with less traction.

Answer (score 8):

I live in a place where one can occasionally see a horse-powered cart used for daily commute and work instead of a show.

They generally use rubber wheels (scrapped from cars or other wheeled machines).

Why do they use them?

Because scrap cars are much, much easier to source. The alternative is a crafty wheel-making that requires both carpentry and blacksmithing skills - and the payload becomes limited.

On the other hand, rubber wheels have more rolling resistance (reducing the horse speed and endurance) and perform worse in mud. They both adhere to the mud and tend to slip sideways.

Comment: I think the use of ball bearings on 2nd hand wheels sourced from cars may be something that can be listed as an advantage.

Comment: I used to drive horses occasionally.  I used whatever carts/traps could be sourced cheaply and locally, and ended up with four of them. Three had pneumatic tyres and at least two of those looked like the wheels were purpose-built, although they might have been sized to fit a common motorbike tyre.  The fourth had thin, solid rubber on huge wheels.  My guess is that most horse drivers won't put up with the extra noise of metal rims on metalled roads.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi the bearings of the motor car wheels are profoundly over-engineered for a horse cart. The whole thing is heavier and has higher resistance than the traditional wood-and-metal horsecart wheel. The only advantage in this regard is that it will never, ever require any maintenance. The horsecart wheels have to be maintained, maybe even daily in heavy use.

Comment: @PastychomperthanksMonica The horsecart drivers I am familiar with will put up with everything as long as the scrap metal or firewood they work with goes to the nearest trading point. Thin solid rubber is no-go because it will wear quickly.

Answer (score 6):

The big win for pneumatic rubber tyres wasn't with cars, it was with bicycles.

Penny-farthing bicycles needed those huge wheels because the spokes were the suspension which enabled the bicycle to travel smoothly over rough ground (and all roads at the time were basically rough ground, of course).  The so-called "safety bicycles" with a more modern shape of frame were commonly known as "boneshakers" because they lacked anything to deal with bumps.  Pneumatic tyres gave safety bicycles the suspension they lacked.  With the reduced size of frame and with compliant tyres, safety bicycles were instantly faster than penny-farthings and the older design died almost immediately.

Bicycles don't need to take very much weight though.  Uprating pneumatic tyres to the point where they could handle the weight of a carriage was *hard*.  Carriages and early cars all used wheels with spokes to give the necessary compliance in the wheel to let the vehicle roll over small bumps, until well into the start of the 20th century.

Comment: Wasn't really the suspension that was the reason for those large wheels, it was (lack of) gearing.  If you look at pictures, you see that the pedals connect directly to the front wheel hub, which also has to turn in order to steer.  So you needed the large wheel to get reasonable travel distance per rotation of the pedals.  Chain drives to the back wheel got this gearing from different sized sprockets (and eventually made multiple gears possible), thus the bike could have smaller wheels of the same size.  Also, wheels with spokes were, and are, more about reducing weight than suspension.

Comment: @jamesqf Wheels with spokes are where the word "suspension" *got its name*. It literally means "to hang"

Comment: @PcMan: Maybe so - we could pass that off to the English site for an answer.  But the "suspension" is not at all the same as the springs & shock absorbers used in automobile or mountain bike suspensions.  They don't do anything noticable for ride, at least in my experience of cars with wire or mag wheels vs the solid steel disks that are (or were) usually low-end stock.  Compare the solid wood wheel of the stereotypical peasant cart to the elegant wooden spokes of a carriage wheel, and it's easy to see that the primary advantage is lower weight.

Answer (score 5):

A big advantage of rubber over iron-shod tyres is *grip*.  Grip matters when braking as well as when accelerating, and carriages had brakes. So if you're descending steep hills, rubber will have an advantage on pretty much any surface.  Grip is also important when cornering at all but the slowest speeds.

Mediaeval dirt roads would be mud roads at some times of year, and wider tyres would help here to reduce sinking. Although width doesn't necessarily require rubber, iron would add weight, and this is weight below any suspension.

Solid rubber provides next to no suspension value, unlike pneumatic tyres, and the construction of inner tubes is much harder than a solid rubber tyre (especially the valves).  Pneumatic tyres would be nice but would need a much higher technology level.

Whether this adds up to a game-changing benefit is another matter - a slightly reduced risk of accidents descending probably isn't worth the extra cost/difficulty of repair, but being able to transport over a longer season than rivals could be very benefificial

Comment: The real advantage of rubber tires wouldn't be fully realized until dirt/gravel roads gave way to flattop pavement, made from concrete or asphalt/tarmac.  You might get some advantage on cobblestone or brick roads, which are hard-surfaced, rather than the loose dirt and rocks of most roads prior to that.

Comment: The bigger offset here than purchase cost or maintenance cost would be the loss of efficiency. ‘grip’ is really just another word for friction, and more friction means more energy lost. Rubber tires on things like bikes are tolerated because they have enough mechanical advantage to offset the energy loss from friction and they happen to need the friction (otherwise they would take too long to accelerate (or brake, but that’s just accelerating as well)).

Comment: @Austin *rolling* friction doesn't have to mean energy loss, but deformation of modern rubber tyres does. For the same width on mud, solid rubber and iron would have similar losses as pushing mud out of the way is lossy, but iron would be heavier on the uphills and provide less braking traction on the downs

Answer (score 1):

The inefficiency comes from lifting and dropping the whole carriage.  Mechanical engineers talk about sprung weight.  If a single wheel can lift over the cobble, it takes less energy than lifting the whole corner of the cart.

A modern car has two sources of suspension:  The springs, and the pneumatic tire.  The tire absorbes the small things, the springs the large things.

While a solid rubber tire on a cart won't make a lot of difference in energy efficiency, it will make the ride a LOT quieter when in the city on cobble streets.

---

Look at harness racing rigs.  They use what amount to two bicycle wheels.  A metal spoke wheel is lighter (less unsprung weight)